# Given set of strings and set of sub-strings as different arrays. How to Find the correct match one from each of the arrays?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let A = ["stack","overflow","algorithm"] , 
    B = ["gor","tac","flo"]. 
A and B are array of strings where B has the substrings.

It is guaranteed that every string in B will be a substring to only one string in A and every string in A have only one match in B. Also consider that the number of strings in A and B are equal.

Output B. Such that B[i] should be substring of A[i].

The output for the above example is:

B = ["tac","flo","gor"].

I can only think of the naive approach. Do we have better solution to the above problem?

Comment: Not sure yet if this is important but: 1) are substrings always the same size (here 3)? 2) is the set of characters always limited in some way? (e.g. only lowercase English letters)

Comment: Substrings can be of any size and set of characters are not limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make concatenation of all strings into superstring `s` of length `L=sum(len(i))`, store indexes of string beginnings.

Build suffix array for superstring  (`LlogL`)

Search every substring in that suffix array  `(N*logL)`

Get string corresponding to this index

---

If substring cannot fit between found position and index of the next string beginning, use another suffix (situation like `fax/emotion/axel` and searching `axe`)

Comment: What if some strings allow for more than one substring match? Don't we then have a set cover problem?

Comment: @גלעד ברקן Source strings cannot match to some substrings and vice versa - due to the second paragraph of problem definition. But superstring perhaps can. Exact cover requires pairwise comparing to set graph edges - like naive approach

Answer (score 0):

I assume by naive approach you mean for each substring in B scan through all words in A to find a match. This approach will have a complexity of **O(n^2)**

However, you can also try to index the words in A using a [Substring Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring_index). Building this index usually requires O(n * log n) construction time.

Afterwards you can utilize this index to efficiently (usually O(log n))  find words that contain a substring. Doing this for every substring in B is thus **O(n * log n)**